# sum of even terms in the fibonacci series less than 4 million

Tags: c

```
////Even Fibonacci numbers
    int i=2;
    int sum_of_Even=0;
    int fib_array[]={};
    fib_array[0]=1;
    fib_array[1]=1; 
    while (fib_array[i]<4000000)
    {
        fib_array[i]=fib_array[i-1]+fib_array[i-2];
        if ((fib_array[i]%2) == 0)
        {
            sum_of_Even+=fib_array[i];
        }
         i++;
    }
    printf("sum of Even terms in the fib sequence = %i\n", sum_of_Even);
```

On the terminal, the output is 3.. Help!
    Program looks good...but somehow gives an output of 3 (which is pretty wrong).. 
    Open to suggestions on how to fix this..
    Thanks..

Comment: what's the size of fib_array?  can you post the complete code ?

Comment: Please post more of your code. Here's a simple hint, int doesn't have enough precision to store many fibonacci values.

Comment: Try to sum upto the next number in the series (greater than 4000000) rather than upto 4000000 and see if the result changes. In case it does, then you can sure that the int is unable to contain the result.

Comment: For the record: this is a Project Euler question, and people are strongly discouraged from posting solutions to these online.

Comment: c int is 16bit, and yours is signed, so the largest value you can store is 32767... you'll never reach a fibonnacci value greater than that.

Comment: @MarcB C `int`s are not 16 bit.  This is implementation-dependent but almost any modern implementation has `int`s of size at least 32 bits.

Comment: I have now specified the size of my array to 300. I also changed sum_of_Even and fib_array from int to long.. but the output is now zero.

Comment: @user3145260 please read the second half of my answer, below

Comment: @Andrey "any modern implementation has ints of size at least 32 bits." is not supported in the embedded world where in 2013 _100 of millions_ of processors/year are made with a 16-bit `int`.  C is heavily used in this non-trivial and well employed market.

Comment: @chux yes, that's very true and very fair.  I somehow doubt that the OP is working on an embedded system.

Comment: @Andrey Agreed.  OP's training may lead to embedded and better to know portable code practices as the C spec only requires an `int` range of at least -32767 to 32767.  Using a `long` here is a better solution.

Comment: @chux fair complaints, but OP is stuck on Problem 2 of Project Euler.  These comments really have nothing to do with him and he probably has no clue what we are talking about.  My comment was really a reply to MarcB's comment which seemed to suggest that in most (all??) cases, C's `int` type is 16 bits, and outside of the special case of embedded software this is just not true.

Comment: @Andrey Agreed with your goal. The certitude of "c int is 16bit" is at best mis-leading, but "C ints are not 16 bit" and "almost any modern implementation has ints of size at least 32 bits" tilted the response too far the other way.  In C, `int` need to be at least 16 bits.  Curiously, @Jules suggests the answer exceeds the 32-bit range.

Comment: @chux For the record, the answer is less than 5 million.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.. I took all ur advices  and it finally works!..

Answer (score 5):

The problem is likely here:  (Anyway this is a big problem even if it is not *the* problem.)

```
int fib_array[]={};
```

The space allocated for your array in memory will not grow dynamically as you appear to expect.  You need to manage the memory for it somehow.  Right now you are overflowing this array substantially and it is amazing that this program does not crash or segfault.

**Edit:** Moreover, *every time* your `while` loop checks its condition for whether to run again, it accesses an entry in your array which has not been initialized!  Note:

- On the first run, it checks whether `fib_array[2] < 4000000`, which you are about to set in the body of the loop!
- On the second run, it checks whether `fib_array[3] < 4000000`, which you are about to set in the body of the loop!
- Etc.

**Edit 2:** Since (amazingly many) people have been posting that you need to use a 64 bit integer and that this is the source of your problems, I'd like to make the clarifying remark that the answer is in the 5 million range, so a 32 bit integer is plenty big.

Comment: There is about ~50% chance that the while loop will exit for each i. That's why it doesn't segfault.

Comment: @self. yes, very good point.  Although it is incredibly mysterious how he gets a sum of `3`, when at each step he is only adding *even numbers* to his sum, which is correctly initialized to `0`.

Comment: @Andrey it's likely that it ruins the stack thus fib_array[?] may modify sum_of_Even. but's it's depends on the architecture and abi.

Comment: @tristan yes, that's a likely explanation.  Although in that case `i` is probably also getting clobbered and the third (or so) access of `fib_array[i]` should *really* result in a crash of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

fib_array[i] is not initialized when you access it in the while() test.  Try changing your while loop to `while(true)` and using `if (fib_array[i]<4000000) break;` on the line after you set fib_array[i].

Also, your sum_of_Even is going to need to be a 64 bit integer, so you'll need:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

and then declare it as `uint64_t`.

Another problem is you aren't declaring how large your fib_array should be, so no actual memory is being allocated to it.  Try `int fib_array[MAXSIZE];` where MAXSIZE is your calculation for how many entries it will need.

Comment: `sum_of_Even` need not exceed 32 bits.

Comment: Agree with @Andrey, answer is more like a 7 digit phone number.

Comment: Ok, I'll grant I don't know the actual answer and was just estimating it as (max value in an iteration) x (max realistic number of iterations) and noting that it might be close to the limit.  But when working within a few orders of magnitude of MAXINT I find it's usually worth switching to a 64-bit int just in case.

Comment: It turns out I'm not the only one to make that assumption, too: see for example the answer to this problem at http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-problem-2/ where the author also concludes that the upper bound of the answer is high enough to warrant a 64 bit int.

Comment: 5 million is about 3 orders of magnitude below the upper limit of a 32 bit integer.  It takes like, a minute to solve the problem exactly, or a few moments' thought to convince yourself that the answer won't be near 10^9.  I think it's irresponsible to tell the OP that (quote) "`sum_of_Even` is going to need to be a 64 bit integer" when that isn't close to being the case and it is *easy* to figure out that it isn't close to being the case.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't clear from the problem statement that the answer will be in the order of 5 million.  My top-of-the-head estimate was closer to 400 million, and other than actually running the calculation it doesn't seem easy to me.  What's the harm in switching to 64 bits when working with unknown values that are potentially within a few orders of magnitude of MAXINT?

Comment: There is no harm in using the larger `int` size.  The harm is telling the OP that that is where his mistake was.  The point is that we have 3 out of 4 answerers in this thread fumbling around telling OP to change the size of his data containers when this is totally irrelevant.  Apparently none of those answerers took the 2-3 minutes to code a solution (takes what, 5 lines?) and just see the answer.

Comment: @Andrey The size is not _totally_ irrelevant.  True, this answer, overstated the requirement for 64-bit, but later cited why conservative programming would suggest it anyways.  Consider a huge blunder where it was incorrectly assumed the rang was good [Ariane 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5_Flight_501).  Not knowing _a priori_ the answer, a quick 5 line 32-bit solution would be in question.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions on how to fix:

And mindful of @Andrey comment:
"For the record: this is a Project Euler question, and people are strongly discouraged from posting solutions to these online."

Use an array of `long long fib_array[3]`.  To generate Fibonacci numbers only the previous 2 are used to generate the 3rd.  After generating a Fibonacci number and testing for evenness, now that you have 3 Fibonacci numbers, discard the eldest and repeat.

---

OP's present `int fib_array[]={};` is not allocating the array needed for OP's approach.   `fib_array[i]=` causes UB.

---

Per @Jules solution, even a `long` may be insufficient, consider `long long`.  In anycase , use the matching `prinf()` format specifier.  Edit: Turns out the answer is < 5,000,000, so `long` will work.

```
long sum_of_Even = 0;
....
printf("sum of Even terms in the fib sequence = %li\n", sum_of_Even);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    long i,s=0,f[50];
    f[0]=1;
    f[1]=1;
    for (i=2;f[i]<4000000;i++){
        f[i] = f[i-1] + f[i-2];
        if (f[i]%2 == 0){
            printf("%ld ",f[i]);
            s += f[i];
        }
    }
    printf("SUM = %ld\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wish I could downvote again, ideone.com/sGKd01 shows the wrong answer.